# How to find a number which is the result of added which elements in the array(Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, there is an array `arr[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]`, each element represents a permission. This is the number used for permission assignment.

One number which is definitely the sum of an element or several elements in an array.

For example:

```
1 = arr[0]

6 = arr[1]+arr[2]

11 = arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[3]

17 = 1 + 16

171 = 1 +2 +8 +32 +128
```

How to find this element or several elements coding with js?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the Javascript? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you probably don't really care what's going on here since it very much smells like an assignment of some sort, this is exactly how answerer feels when asker do not provide enough information that helps with answering the question.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]

const getElementIndexes = (n) => {
  return arr.slice().reverse().reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (n >= currentValue) {
      accumulator.unshift(arr.indexOf(currentValue))
      n = n - currentValue
    }
    return accumulator
  }, [])
}

console.log(getElementIndexes(1))
console.log(getElementIndexes(6))
console.log(getElementIndexes(11))
console.log(getElementIndexes(17))
console.log(getElementIndexes(171))
```

Comment: Sorry，My English is terrible.

Comment: 谢谢，这正是我想要的 Thank you, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @ioripalm You're welcome. Ask a good question if you want a good answer. 不客气。想要好答案，先写好问题。